# How to Create content type per organic group

Tags: nodes, organic-groups

Hi i have created a content type and i have 4 groups using organic groups.

Is there any way i can restrict content type to one of the organic group.so other groups cant create any content with the content type.

Please help me thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by restricted? Do you mean only the members of one group should be able to create the content? Sounds like Rules to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add taxonomy terms to differentiate different content types.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict one content type to only one organic group,you can:

1. You may create a vocabulary with any name. For example: `organicgroups`.
2. You may add lists (terms) to that vocabulary.
3. Then while creating a content, associate a vocabulary term with each content node as per the organic group for which you are creating the content.